# Regular expressions mystery: "No ending delimiter '^' found"

Tags: regex, filter-var

Can someone explain to me?
This is my code :

```
 $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+'
            . '(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 
    if (preg_match($regex, $email)) {
        echo $email . " is a valid email. We can accept it.";
    } else { 
        echo $email . " is an invalid email. Please try again.";
    }
```

If I use for an example this regular expression:

```
^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)↪*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$
```

or another different regular expression I get:

```
preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found
```

And if I use `filter_var('some_regular_expression', FILTER_EMAIL_VALIDATOR)` an email like `asd!qwe@gmail.com` is a valid one ???

Comment: There appears to be a unicode character in your expression throwing off the parser, but Barmar is right, you need to use a delimeter for your expression. Common ones are `/../` or `~..~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `preg_XXX` functions, the first character of the regular expression argument is a delimiter character -- it's `/` in your first example. It must appear at the end of the regular expression, it's used to separate the regular expression from modifier option characters, for instance in:

```
/[a-z]/i
```

the second `/` separates the regular expression from the `i` (case-insensitive) modifier.

So you simply need to change your regular expression to:

```
/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)↪*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/
```

I'm not sure what that `↪` character is in there for, though. It doesn't seem like it's appropriate for validating emails.

And yes, `asd!qwe@gmail.com` is a valid email. Back in the day of UUCP mail transfer, addresses of the form `host1!host2!host3!username@uu.net` were common -- the `!` characters delimited hostnames in the UUCP path. See [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1) for recommendations on email validation.

Comment: nah , i've checked mails like !asd@gmail.com , asd!ko@gmail.com are not valid emails, but thanks for your answer you helped me with the regular expression.

Comment: Maybe Gmail doesn't allow those types of names, but they're allowed by the SMTP standard.